# How many tones in English?

Tags: pronunciation

Every single syllable in Mandarin Chinese contains 4 tones:

> First tone: a level and higher pitch---- mā
> Second tone: rising, start from a lower pitch and end at a slightly higher pitch---- má
> Third tone: falling rising, start at a neutral tone then dip to a lower pitch before ending at a higher pitch---- mǎ
> Fourth tone: falling, start the syllable at a slightly higher than neutral pitch then go quickly and strongly downwards---- mà

There are 6 different tones in Cantonese, two more tones than Mandarin.

So how many tones in English?

Comment: English is not a tonal language, so "tones" in English don't really have the same meaning as tones in Cantonese or Mandarin. They are used for semantic meaning (whether a sentence overall is a question or a statement, for example, or the mood of a sentence), but not for lexical meaning (ie what the word itself means). I have seen some people online saying that English has 5 tones, but most English speakers don't know or think about tones at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike many other languages, English does not have tones or follow this tonal rule.

> They are used for semantic meaning (whether a sentence overall is a question or a statement, for example, or the mood of a sentence), but not for lexical meaning (ie what the word itself means) - @Esther

Although most English speakers rarely hear such thing as a tone in english, some websites online say there are 5 tones.

> Helping students to use intonation effectively to convey attitude in English will involve helping students to make the five tones (falls or rises in pitch): fall, rise, slight rise, fall followed by a rise, rise followed by a fall, through awareness raising and modelling of the common intonation patterns in context. [Tones | teachingenglish](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/article/tone&ved=2ahUKEwiPqbfCrfL3AhXcILcAHbHCAN8QFnoECBEQBQ&usg=AOvVaw0ZBw1I_uaLnxeJeqLGVZ95)